# IntelliJ Update Bugzilla through Perforce Checkin

Tags: intellij-idea, perforce, bugzilla

When I check in a file to Perforce using IntelliJ I would like the check-in to update Bugzilla as well.  I have connected to both Perforce and Bugzilla within IntelliJ.

Is there a way to do this check-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this check-in?

Use Tasks Integration. Open new tasks from a Bugzilla issue, do the changes you need, then close the task. On closing tasks, use the option to commit changes.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html

Comment: Ok, this process makes sense to me.  When I go tools / tasks & contents / open task  I see a small menu with no list items from Bugzilla.  In Preferences / Tasks / Servers I am using http://bugzilla.company.com/xmlrpc.cgi.  This tests successfully.  I wonder what I could be missing?

Comment: I had to install the Bugzilla Task Provider plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5054-bugzilla-task-provider to get the integration to work.  And I used the URI:   http://bugzilla.company.com.